# I need to generate excel sheet from List<Object> in C#.Net Console application and save it as a file?

Tags: c#, list, console-application

**I have a list List transactionWithError.**

How can I generate excel sheet from this list and then save it using C#.Net console application. One approach is converting to datatable and then changing to excel sheet but since the data in the List is around 1000 rows this approach is my second choice. Can you suggest the best possible way?

```
public class SaveTransactionDetails
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the transaction ID.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The transaction ID.
    /// </value>
    public string TransactionID { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the trans program ID.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The trans program ID.
    /// </value>
    public int TransProgramID { get; set; } //6
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the trans gift hours.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The trans gift hours.
    /// </value>
    public int TransGiftHours { get; set; } // Volunteered hours
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the type of the trans gift.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The type of the trans gift.
    /// </value>
    public int TransGiftType { get; set; } //5
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the trans emp system ID.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The trans emp system ID.
    /// </value>
    public string TransEmpSystemID { get; set; } //JKEmployeeID
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the trans emp VLID.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The trans emp VLID.
    /// </value>
    public int TransEmpVLID { get; set; } //JKEmployeeID
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the name of the trans emp.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The name of the trans emp.
    /// </value>
    public string TransEmpName { get; set; } //JKEmployeeName        
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the trans organization ID.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The trans organization ID.
    /// </value>
    public string TransOrganizationID { get; set; }  // JK nonprofit's organization ID
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the trans gift date.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The trans gift date.
    /// </value>
    public DateTime TransGiftDate { get; set; }   // Today's date
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the trans donor year.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The trans donor year.
    /// </value>
    public int TransDonorYear { get; set; } // year from today's date
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the trans ack reason.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The trans ack reason.
    /// </value>
    public string TransAckReason { get; set; } // Reason
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the trans purpose.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The trans purpose.
    /// </value>
    public string TransPurpose { get; set; } // Purpose
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the trans description.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The trans description.
    /// </value>
    public string TransDescription { get; set; } // Summary
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the opportunity or activity attended ID.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The opportunity or activity attended ID.
    /// </value>
    public int OpportunityOrActivityAttendedID { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether this instance is opportunity.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    ///     <c>true</c> if this instance is opportunity; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
    /// </value>
    public bool IsOpportunity { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the trans status ID.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The trans status ID.
    /// </value>
    public int TransStatusID { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the trans user1.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The trans user1.
    /// </value>
    public string TransUser1 { get; set; }


    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the trans emp email ID.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The trans emp email ID.
    /// </value>
    public string TransEmpEmailID { get; set; }


    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the name of the trans org.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The name of the trans org.
    /// </value>
    public string TransOrgName { get; set; }


    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the trans org email ID.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The trans org email ID.
    /// </value>
    public string TransOrgEmailID { get; set; }


    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the trans start date.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The trans start date.
    /// </value>
    public DateTime TransStartDate { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the trans end date.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The trans end date.
    /// </value>
    public DateTime TransEndDate { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether this instance is error.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    ///   <c>true</c> if this instance is error; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
    /// </value>
    public Boolean IsError { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the error description.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The error description.
    /// </value>
    public string ErrorDescription { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Enum value specifying email type
/// </summary>
public enum EmailType
{
    /// <summary>
    /// None
    /// </summary>
    None = 0,

    /// <summary>
    /// Volunteer Mail Body
    /// </summary>
    VolunteerSendMail = 1,

    /// <summary>
    /// Nonprofit Mail Body
    /// </summary>
    NonprofitSendMail = 2

}
```

Answer (score 0):

write data in comma seperated formated csv file

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i needed to generate excel sheet in tabular format. This is not exactly what i want.

Comment: you have 3 option thn 1> use com automation if this is not server app 2> Use third party library like EEPlus 3>Understand open xml for office and write data in xml based on open xml spec

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) library to generate Excel file.

Comment: Thanks. But the constraint which i have is to have our own code and not third party library. can you suggest me the code for the above mentioned question?

Comment: @BalrajSingh You are trying to reinvent the wheel. EPPlus is an open source library.

Comment: No i don't want to reinvent EPPlus but just need only that part of code which can help me to generate excel sheet from this list and hence trying to minimize the code and dependency on third party tool.